# mysqldb .. 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mysql-python

This code works fine when the `cur.execute()` and `db.commit()` lines are commented out; i.e. if all I do is print the query, this program runs for n number of rows. The problem seems to occur here:

```
player_categories_statistics = cur.fetchone()
player_id = player_categories_statistics[0]
```

When I try to insert the result, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 72, in <module>
    meat = meatgrind(league_name, categories_measurement_statistics)
  File "test2.py", line 32, in meatgrind
    player_id = int(player_categories_statistics[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

The code:

```
import sys 
import MySQLdb
import string 

db = MySQLdb.connect()
cur = db.cursor('localhost','me',XXXXX,'testdb')


def meatgrind(league_name,categories_measurement_statistics):
# a varied range of different categories can be used 

    # 1. list categories
    categories = []
    categories_string = "player_id"
    categories_string_newtable = "meatgrinded_player_id, player_id"
    for category in categories_measurement_statistics:
        categories_string += ", " + category[0]
        categories_string_newtable += ", " + category[0]


    # 2. get players and statistics
    query = "SELECT %s FROM players" % (categories_string)
    cur.execute("%s" % (query))
    # rowcount = int(cur.rowcount)
    rowcount = 2 #hard-coded for debugging

    # 3. meatgrind one player at a time
    meatgrinded_player_id = 1
    for i in range(rowcount):
        player_categories_statistics = cur.fetchone()
        player_id = player_categories_statistics[0]

        #4. grind a category statistic
        meatgrindings_string = "%d, %d" % (meatgrinded_player_id, player_id)

        index = 1
        for category in categories_measurement_statistics:

            # SOME MATH HERE resulting in player_meatgrindings

            meatgrindings_string += ", %0.4f" % player_meatgrindings



query = """INSERT INTO sometable (%s) VALUES (%s)""" % (categories_string_newtable, meatgrindings_string)
cur.execute("%s" % (query))
db.commit()

meatgrinded_player_id += 1


league_name = 'test'
categories_measurement_statistics = (('H', 156.3, 19.643093216474604), ('HR', 21.3, 9.003147597738618), ('SB', 13.25, 16.041179646286754))

meat = meatgrind(league_name, categories_measurement_statistics)
```

Comment: You'll have to edit your code to have the correct formatting - otherwise your meatgrind function looks like invalid syntax :) I'd do it, but I could only guess where the function ends.

Comment: Are you sure you have data in your `players` table?

Comment: players table is chock full .. I'm kinda new at this .. so if meat grind() fails, i'm embarrassed, but doesn't it pass a simple string and the tuple of tuples in categories_measurement_statitistics? That seems to pass fine, but maybe there is something i don't see.

Comment: @NathanHoad the meat grind function starts and ends with this single call. You see everything that is passed into this call.

Comment: @Cole then correct your indentation to reflect that?

Comment: editing was a tab vs space problem. one tab = eight chars (in my browser) which provides correct indentation while editing, but sucks while rendering because propably the SO engine treats a tab as 4 spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your error is:

```
player_categories_statistics = cur.fetchone()
```

This sets `player_categories_statistics` to `None`.  `None[0]` raises the exception.

The only reason this would happen is your query returns no rows, which means your table is empty.  Your table is most likely is empty because you never put any rows in it, or less likely you removed them somehow.

I culprit **may** be the following, you are inserting into `sometable` and selecting from `players`:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (%s) VALUES (%s)
```

vs

```
SELECT %s FROM players
```

The only reason this is possible is because your forcing it to loop even if nothing was returned with the line:

```
rowcount = 2 #hard-coded for debugging
```

---

Additional Info:

Here's a working query I ran on an sqlite3 database with a single table with a single row with nearly identical statements as yours, just to show that yours should be working if the data is indeed there.

```
query = "SELECT %s FROM customer" % 'first_name, last_name'

row = c.execute("%s" % (query)).fetchone()

row
Out[28]: (u'Derek', u'Litz')
```

Here's another working query on a sqlite3 database with another table and no rows.

```
query = "SELECT %s FROM customer2" % 'first_name, last_name'

print c.execute("%s" % (query)).fetchone()
None
```

As you can see, identical to the behavior above.

Also make sure rowcount works they way you want with your DB. It doesn't with sqlite3, for example.  See rowcount spec in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor_objects and consulte MySQLdb docs.

Comment: I was such a novice, including a novice at using stackoverflow, that I didn't know about checking answers. Your's was a very thoughtful one, and so I'm stink in this long-overdue note to thank you